# Wordpress allow page permalink to be a date (year) without appending a -2 at the end

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

When creating a page as 2020 as the title the permalink created becomes 2020-2 but would like it to be 2020 for example https://www.example.com/2020/ - to load a page with that name, not the archive page of the year 2020.

I know this must be because of year permalink being reserved by the Yearly Archive of the site, but is there a way to alter this so that the archives and their permalink generation are disabled (not redirected) so that opens up the ability for pages to be named as a year?

Answer (score 0):

Permalink 2020-2  is because you have already created a page as 2020 so the next one becomes 2020-2 same for all the pages. Try changing the permalink structure in admin side of WordPress `Settings->permalink->`and choose the option of `POST NAME` .
The date won't appear on the URL . There is more options to customize the permalink structure also.

Comment: Thanks for responding - but hmm not quite, there is no other page 2020... I have seen before (for example) where if a Media Library attachment is uploaded, it creates a permalink for it - if you then create a page of the same name as that file it will get a -2 at the end of the permalink unless you change the media library permalink to something else...

Similarly, as mentioned, I imagine because 2020 is reserved for Year Archives so when you go to /2020/ it will try to load the Archive template for posts posted in the year 2020... so I need this disabled to make way for pages.

Comment: @Ricky I'm too facing the same issue. Let me know if you have found a workaround